# AsyncTask/ or Thread causes list view row to populate value only when scrolled

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My app consists of a custom list view and each row contains text.

My MainActivity `puts` the translated strings into a HashMap called `feedData` which is retrieved by a `CustomListView Class` where the `TextView` for each row is set.

Everything about my custom list view performs perfectly. I am getting this error because I'm implementing the Google API Translation which forces me to use AsyncTask or a Thread. The values populate into each row but only when I scroll up and down.

**MainActivity**

```
  TranslateString(feedText, feedData);
  arrayFeedList.add(feedData);
```

**Translate String Method:**

```
 public void TranslateString(final String mText, final HashMap<String, String> mList) {



                    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                            try {
                                Translate translate = TranslateOptions.builder().setApiKey("AIzaSyB7cCDBbeoZ2tYTH-Ynv25OaPraLmTG7Hw").build().getService();
                                Translation translation =
                                        translate.translate(
                                                mText,
                                                TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("tr"),
                                                TranslateOption.targetLanguage("en"));
                                returnedString = translation.getTranslatedText();

                                check = 1;

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                 check = 2;

                            }

                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            if(check == 1){
                                mList.put("feed", returnedString);
                            }
                            else if(check == 2){
                                mList.put("feed", mText + " " + getContext().getString(R.string.translationfailed) + " in catch");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    asyncTask.execute();       
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in my MainActivity fixed my problem: (After deleting the AsyncTask Method Completely)

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```